# OOM-Error on Layers i dont want to train (Transfer Learning)

Tags: python, keras, transfer-learning

I am currently working on a project were i try to compare serval Neural Networks ,one of them being a model to classify the cifar10 dataset with a model trained on top of the VGG16.

I Do not have any problems when training the other models but with the VGG16 i get and Out of Memory Error allthough i dont want to train the Layer in Question.

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras

from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import keras.losses as losses
import keras.optimizers as optimizers

from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.datasets import cifar10

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

import cv2

cwd =os.getcwd()


#defining later used variables such as data paths and img sizes
which_data = 'cifar10'

img_size =32
img_depth =3
batch_size=20
class_count = 10
use_percentage=0.5

input_shape=(img_size, img_size, img_depth)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

x_train = x_train[:int((x_train.shape[0]*use_percentage))]
y_train = y_train[:int((y_train.shape[0]*use_percentage))]


x_test = x_test[:int((x_test.shape[0]*use_percentage))]
y_test = y_test[:int((y_test.shape[0]*use_percentage))]


print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'reduced train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'reduced test samples')

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, class_count)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, class_count)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255


steps_per_epoch= x_train.shape[0]//batch_size
validation_steps =x_test.shape[0]//batch_size
epochs= 20
verbose =1 ### information output


##VGG16 Model
input_tensor = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
model=VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_tensor=input_tensor)

layer_dict =dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])


X = layer_dict['block5_pool'].output

X = layers.Flatten()(X)
X = layers.Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(X)



transfer_simple = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=X)

for layer in transfer_simple.layers[:19]:
    layer.trainable = False


print(transfer_simple.summary())


transfer_simple.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.02),metrics=['accuracy'])


ts_history=transfer_simple.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=verbose,
        shuffle=True
)


transfer_simple.save_weights(which_data+'/advanced_cnn'+epochs+'_weights.h5')
```

The summary of the Model states that only  5,130 are trainable parameters i still get the following Error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[25000,64,32,32] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[Node: block1_conv1_5/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block1_conv1_5/convolution-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, block1_conv1_5/kernel/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[Node: loss_5/mul/_1255 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_402_loss_5/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

I am at my wits end and really hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

While i didnt figure out the solution to this problem i kinda found a way around it. Instead of using the fit() function to train my neural networking i used the following:

```py
training_stream = ImageDataGenerator().flow(x=x_train,y=y_train,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True
        )
validation_stream = ImageDataGenerator().flow(x=x_test,y=y_test,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True
        )

ts_history=transfer_simple.fit_generator(
        training_stream,
        validation_data=validation_stream,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        validation_steps=validation_steps,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=verbose,
        shuffle=True
)
```

This seemsto handle the input data in smaller chunks and eliminates the OOM-Error

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why you run OOM but the first things to check:

- Is your batch_size to big? Reduce the batch_size
- Weird stuff happend in your current session: `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` often helps, sometimes you have to restart your kernel
- Is your network too big?

Try to estimate you memory requirements:

```
def get_model_memory_usage(batch_size, model):
shapes_mem_count = 0
for l in model.layers:
    single_layer_mem = 1
    for s in l.output_shape:
        if s is None:
            continue
        single_layer_mem *= s
    shapes_mem_count += single_layer_mem

trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.trainable_weights)])
non_trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.non_trainable_weights)])

number_size = 4.0
if K.floatx() == 'float16':
     number_size = 2.0
if K.floatx() == 'float64':
     number_size = 8.0

total_memory = number_size*(batch_size*shapes_mem_count + trainable_count + non_trainable_count)
gbytes = np.round(total_memory / (1024.0 ** 3), 3)
return gbytes
```